# How can I test an iPhone app on my iPhone that is Jailbroken?

Tags: iphone, restore, jailbreak, cydia

Unfortunately I went the route to jailbreak my iPhone in Thailand so I could use the SIM over there, but now that I'm back and in development mode needing to test an iPhone app I truly regret doing it.

I have tried to restore the old iPhone version but can't seem to be able to do it, I get an error 1015 after trying to restore the iPhone. I've pointed to a new firmware install and still get the same error.

The only thing I can now do to get my iPhone to work is install another jailbroken OS on it (not sure if that is the right term, anyway it is sn0wbreeze_iPhone 3GS-4.3.1.ipsw Cydia).

Does anyone know how I can test my iPhone app on this? I'd need specific instructions as I'm new to this. Or even better, does anyone know how I can get rid of Cydia and just get the real firmware/os on it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked if your /etc/hosts file has been modified with a line that prevent to check your iPhone against the Apple server? If so you need to remove it. If you are on a windows OS you can check the location of the hosts file here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)

Then you should be able to restore your iPhone back to the original firmware.

Answer (score 0):

This works for sure
http://cellphones.about.com/od/howtoguides/ss/restore_iphone.htm

Also about testing your app. I suppose its on XCODE, well after you successful restoration. You have to follow the official Apple Guide. From the Developer Center. You do not have to pay the annual fee. Please tell me if you need something else.

ps: i developed pwnmail on cydia. So feel free to ask ;)

Answer (score 0):

Alex Whittemore has a great set of tutorials for testing and debugging on jailbroken iPhones, for many versions of iOS and XCode. [Here](http://www.alexwhittemore.com/?s=developing%20jailbroken) you go.